# Select data based on a distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, normal-distribution

I have a set of data in a vector. If I were to plot a histogram of the data I could see (by clever inspection) that the data is distributed as the sum of three distributions;

One normal distribution centered around x_1 with variance s_1;
One normal distribution centered around x_2 with variance s_2;
Once lognormal distribution.

My data is obviously a subset of the 'real' data.

What I would like to do is to take a random subset of my data away from my data ensuring that the resulting subset is a reasonable representative sample of the original data.

I would like to do this as easily as possible in matlab but am new to both statistics and matlab and am unsure where to start.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Perhaps belongs to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure it is a reasonable representative sample"? If you just sampled randomly from your data set, in what way would that not be "reasonably representative"? (Not a rhetorical question - I'd like you to answer it so that I can be sure what you're asking!)

Comment: I agree with @ChrisTaylor. If your subset is large enough, usually you can assume that the distribution is the same. You can apply `randperm` function to randomly select data subset without replacements.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Let's say that my problem is more trivial and I knew my data should represent a normal distribution however if i plot a histogram of my data i can see that some of the bins may be under or over subscribed. I cannot take out too many of the points accidentally from and under subscribed bin (as it will corrupt the data) and I prefer not to take too many points from an over subscribed bin.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify each of the 3 distributions (in the sense that you can estimate their parameters), one approach could be to select a random subset of your data and then try to estimate the parameters for each distribution and see whether they are close enough (according to your own definition of "close") to the parameters of the original distributions. You should repeat this process several time and look at the average difference given a random subset size.